# Why is ListView.getCheckedItemPositions() not returning correct values?

Tags: android, listview

The app has a **ListView** with multiple-selection enabled, in the UI it works as expected. But when I read the values out using this code:

```
Log.i(TAG,"Entered SearchActivity.saveCategoryChoice()");
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = categorySelector.getCheckedItemPositions();
Log.i(TAG,"checkedPositions: " + checkedPositions.size());

if (checkedPositions != null) {
  int count = categoriesAdapter.getCount();
  for ( int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Selected items: " + checkedPositions.get(i));
  }
}
```

I get this output, no matter what state each checkbox is in:

```
Entered SearchActivity.saveCategoryChoice()
checkedPositions: 0
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
Selected items: false
```

The [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) seems to return false for any non-existent item, so the source of the problems seems to be that getCheckedItemPositions() is returning an empty array. The method is behaving as if there are no items in the ListView, but there are.

I can see from the docs that no values are returned when the ListView is not set up as multi-select, but it is, using this statement:

```
categorySelector.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

In my scenario, the adapter I'm using is a subclass of ArrayAdapter, and (without any solid evidence) I suspect this may be the cause, though I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Pity that I did not see that question (years) sooner but how did you check the items of the ListView? There is neither an obvious error in the above code nor in the result. It should work if you set the checked state with categorySelector.setItemChecked(int position, boolean value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still do not know why, but in my scenario, `getCheckedItemPositions()` returns false values for all items. I cannot see a way to use the methods on the ListView to get the boolean values out. The SparseBooleanArray object seems to have no real-world data in it. I suspect this may be because of some quirk of my implementation, perhaps that I've subclassed ArrayAdapter. It's frustrating, issues like this are a real time-drain.

Anyway, the solution I have used is to to attach a handler to each Checkbox individually as ListView rows are created. So from `ListView.getView()` I call this method:

```
private void addClickHandlerToCheckBox(CheckBox checkbox) {
  checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)arg0; 
        boolean isChecked = checkbox.isChecked();
        // Store the boolean value somewhere durable
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how do you add addClickHandlerToCheckBox for each checkbox in your checkbox list? thanks.

Comment: May be the problem was the view returned from adapter's getView() had not implemented Checkable interface.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but was caused by the selection being cleared by a confirmation dialog.  You need to clone the `SparseBooleanArray` prior to clearing the checked states (automatically).

Answer (score 46):

kcoppock is right, you need to use valueAt(), the working code should be

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = categorySelector.getCheckedItemPositions();
if (checkedItems != null) {
    for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
        if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
            String item = categorySelector.getAdapter().getItem(
                                  checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
            Log.i(TAG,item + " was selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I remember having an issue with this myself a while back. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464636/returning-values-from-multiple-selection-listview/3473645) is my previous question, which isn't directly related to your issue, but contains some code that may help. What you might want to try is using `checkedPositions.valueAt(int index)` rather than `checkedPositions.get(int index)`. I think that may be what you're actually looking for.

Comment: I just tried using valueAt() and for me, for whatever reason, it returns false for all of them, no matter what the checkboxes are set to.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions have worked for me, instead I get every child (a checkedTextView) from the ListView and see if it is checked or not:

```
            ListView myListView = myViewActivity.getListView();
        ArrayList<String> selectedChildren2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0;i<myListView.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            CheckedTextView c = (CheckedTextView) myListView.getChildAt(i);
            if(c.isChecked())
            {
                String child = c.getText().toString();
                selectedChildren.add(child);
                }
        }
```

Comment: This will not work if you have more elements than is visible, as it only iterates through the visible rows.

Answer (score 2):

It happens if you do not choose the correct resource for showing your different items. It works fine if you choose the built-in resource android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice. The method `getCheckedItemPositions` is coupled in some way to the built-in resource.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to handle the checking/unchecking of items within the ListView. It already does it on its own.

What does not seem documented is that the ListView will only do this if:

1. a `ListAdapter` is set and
2. the choice mode is CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and
3. the ids used by the `ListAdapter` are **stable**.

The third point was what drove me crazy for a while.

I am not sure what 'stable' means (I guess that the ids don't ever change while the list is displayed). 
As far as the ListView is concerned, it means that the method `hasStableIds()` in `ListAdapter` returns true.

I created a simple subclass of `ArrayAdapter` like this:

```
public class StableArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

(You already have your subclass, so just add the `hasStableIds` override)

Of course, one needs to add the constructor that one was using with `ArrayAdapter`.

Once you use this class as your `ListAdapter`, `getCheckedItemPositions()` behaves as expected.

One last note: `setChoiceMode` must be called AFTER setting the list adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but since this basically came up first in current Google search here's a quick way to understand what `listView.getCheckedItemPositions()` does:

**Unless the list Item wasn't 'toggled' at all in your ListView, it wont be added to the SparseBooleanArray that is returned by `listView.getCheckedItemPositions()`**

But then, you really don't want your users to click every list item to "properly" add it to the returned SparseBooleanArray right?

Hence you need to combine the usage of **valueAt()** AND **keyAt()** of the SparseBooleanArray for this.

```
    SparseBooleanArray checkedArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    ArrayList<DataEntry> entries = baseAdapter.getBackingArray(); //point this to the array of your custom adapter

    if (checkedArray != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < checkedArray.size(); i++)
        {
            if(checkedArray.valueAt(i))    //valueAt() gets the boolean
                entries.yourMethodAtIndex(checkedArray.keyAt(i)); //keyAt() gets the key
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem of the author was the checkedPositions.size() (checkedArray.size() in your case) always returned 0.

Comment: The big question is, why the check doesn't  `SparseBooleanArray checkedArray =  listView.getCheckedItemPositions()` clear items that are currently unchecked but were checked in the past!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a rather fundamental difference between `'selected'` and `'checked'`?

Suspect you want to `setItemChecked()` from an `OnItemSelectedListener`...

Comment: You're right that I've muddied checked & selected in my question a bit, but... the docs for getCheckedItemPositions() do state that the selection mode must be multiple or it returns null. I have also tried getCheckItemIds() and that also returns an empty collection. I suspect I will end up using a listener, but I'm curious to understand why the methods aren't working intuitively.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing why they made the selection mode relevant at all. Having looked through ListView.java just now, it seems to me that unless you call setItemChecked() yourself I don't think you will get the automatic checked state toggling that you are (quite reasonably) assuming should happen when the item is selected. The only automatic checked state toggling that I can see happens when list items are added, and only then if your View-derived class implements Checkable. It would be good if default selection handling did the same thing...

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, but still pretty confusing. If I have a multiple-selection ListView with checkboxes and there's a method called getCheckedItemIds() it seems reasonable to assume it will provide the status. But I've reimplemented it using a handler on OnCheckedChangeListener and that's working fine, in fact using getTag() it's a nice and clean approach. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This adjustment fixed it for me.
Change the getView method so that "int position" is "final int position".
Then do this with your checkbox:

```
((CheckBox) convertView).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    list.setItemChecked(position, ((CheckBox) buttonView).isChecked());
                }
            });
```

Let me elaborate.
list is a reference to the listview and in my case the adapter is an inner class in the dialog holding the list.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread by having the same problem but I think I have come up with a workaround that worked for me for unkown reasons. Whenever I tried getting a value I got nothing but if I loop through the list setting all to false it started working just like intended.

This was actually a feature I had implemented where the user could either "Select All" or "Unselect All". I run this method in my onCreate.

```
private void selectNone() {
    ListView lv = getListView();
    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
        lv.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
}
```

Now all my values are correct. For getting the values, in my case, just Strings.

```
private void importSelected() {     
    ListView lv = getListView();
    SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        if (selectedItems.get(i)) {
            String item =  lv.getAdapter().getItem(selectedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
        }
    }

    selectNone(); //Reset
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I too used the solution gyller suggests that involves "initiating" the listview

`ListView lv = getListView();
 for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
     lv.setItemChecked(i, false);
 }`

before calling getCheckItemPositions(), and it stopped producing erroneous results!

Answer (score 0):

while I do not believe I have tried every variation described here, here is the one that has worked for me :)

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

            CheckedTextView retView = (CheckedTextView) convertView;
...
            retView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    CheckedTextView chkVw = (CheckedTextView) v; 
//                  chkVw.toggle();
//                  chkVw.setChecked(!chkVw.isChecked());
                    mLstVwWordingSets.setItemChecked(position + 1, !chkVw.isChecked());
                }
            });
...
       }
```

And later

```
        SparseBooleanArray checkedItemsArray = mLstVwWordingSets.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 1; i <  mLstVwWordingSets.getCount(); i++)         //skip the header view
        {
            if (checkedItemsArray.get(i, false))
                Log.d(_TAG, "checked item: " + i);
        }
```

I am accessing position + 1 due to a header view that my list has in place.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar_CheckedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

for each holer of check box i am using to store it in array

```
holder.chk_Allow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked)
                        ar_CheckedList.add(position);
                }
            });
```

on click of button

```
for (int i = 0; i <  ar_CheckedList.size(); i++)
 {
        HashMap<String, String> temp=(HashMap<String, String>) contactList.get(ar_CheckedList.get(i));
        str_Phone_No=temp.get(TAG_CONTACT_MOBILE);
        send(str_Phone_No);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> selectedChildren = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0;i<list.getChildCount();i++)
{
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox) list.getChildAt(i);
    if(c.isChecked())
    {
        String child = c.getText().toString();
        selectedChildren.add(child);
    }
}
Log.i(TAG, "onClick: " + selectedChildren.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

simply go to the xml where your listview is defined and set property

```
**android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"**
```

my xmlfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCustomList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and then in your javafile as:-

```
SparseBooleanArray checked=lvDetail.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < lvDetail.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
if (checked.get(i)) {             
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),checked.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           

   }
}
```