# Delete selected item from listview not working

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclick, selecteditem

so I have a listview and trying to be able to delete the selected item in the listview.So far, heres my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    Button button3;
    Button button2;
    Button button4;
    ListView listView1;
    ListView listView2;
    Spinner s1;
    String text;
    Integer i;
    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions ;


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    int itemPos;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); 
            button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4); 
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);



            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, list);
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

                button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String text = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        list.add(text); 
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    }});

                adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, list2);
                    listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

                    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            String text = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            list2.add(text); 
                            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        }});

                    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //part to remove item
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            /** Getting the checked items from the listview */
                            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = listView1.getCheckedItemPositions();


                            for(int i=itemPos-1; i >= 0; i--){
                                if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                                    adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                            checkedItemPositions.clear();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });



     listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

            view.setSelected(true);

        itemPos = position;

      }});
    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

                view.setSelected(true);

            itemPos = position;

          }
    });}}
```

listview defined in xml like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_key" > >
</ListView>
```

However, when I click delete, it just unmark the item and it doesnt remove it from the list at all.I dont know how to solve this.Im a beginner in android/java also.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should also remove the item from the list:

```
adapter.remove(list.get(i));
list.remove(i);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Generally, it works. However, you can use one trick is to create the adapter and add it again.

```
...
list.remove(i);
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, list);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: it still does the same thing

Comment: I added the xml  of my listview

Comment: When I add this, I get error The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Comment: Yes, sorry. This should be changed to MainActivity.this as updated answer.

Comment: I did that, application run, but item doesnt get removed from list;just get unmarked

Comment: I think it didn't enter the loop. Please check it and refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352990/listview-getcheckeditempositions-not-able-to-return-checked-items-in-sparseboole

Comment: Well I added your code in the  button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() methode; is it at the right place?

Comment: after list.remove(i);

Comment: Yes, but the problem is your program may never enter the condition checkedItemPositions.get(i) of button3.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer at this link:

[OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener not working for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437673/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-not-working-for-listview/18539885#18539885)

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Not really.. I dont understand :(