# simulate a click from onitemclick

Tags: android

I already have an `onitemclickListener` and it works,

```
list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
{
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
         ...
     }
});
```

however, I need to implement the same functionality from a different button.

How do I reference the `onitemclickListener` that already exists for my list ?

I don't want to copy all the code and use it again as it is about 500 lines.

Comment: performClick() does that, or you could keep your OnItemClickListener in a variable and assign it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your code in a separate method, and call that method from bot the `onItemClick` and `onClick`.

If your code needs the selected item, pass it as an argument from the `onItemClick`. In your button `onClick` you will have to look at the [`ListView.getCheckedItemIds`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds%28%29), since a list view can have more than one item selected at a time, and apply your logic to the items you want, based on whatever criteria.

Comment: Note that my assumption (based on your question wording) is you want to add a `Button`, not another `ListView` If the latter's the case, than you can just follow the other people's advice of creating explicit `OnItemClickedListener` instance and reusing it.

Comment: I have implemented your solution and it almost works. It works for the original method, but for the other button, I get an error Arrayindexoutofbounds when calling this ListItemClick(list.getCheckedItemPosition());

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996938/why-is-listview-getcheckeditempositions-not-returning-correct-values, it might help you. Also, updating your question with some of the new code will allow people here to pinpoint your problem easier.

Answer (score 19):

There is [performItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick%28android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) which does this.

```
list.performItemClick(list.getChildAt(pos), pos, list.getItemIdAtPosition(pos));
```

Comment: Note: [`ViewGroup.getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) will return `null` if the View isn't visible on screen. So if you're using a `ListView` and the item you're trying to programmatically perform a click on is off screen, `getChildAt()` will return `null`. This `null` will eventually be passed to your `onItemClick()` callback, which may not matter to you if you don't need that `View` object, but if you do then try passing in `list.getAdapter().getView()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

create your own `OnItemClickListener` class, that uses the code you have already written, and use that in your calls `list.setOnItemClickListener(new myOnClickListener())`

Answer (score 0):

need to create an OnItemClickListener object and use it Whenever you need like :

```
OnItemClickListener listener =  new OnItemClickListener(){
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                 {
                 ...
                 }
}
```

and Whenever you need:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your onItemClickListener in layout xml and create a common method in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions, either you could write a general function and call this function when either button is clicked. Another solution would be to get a view on the first button when you click on the second button and then call the performClick function.

```
public void Click2()
{
 Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

 b.performClick();

}
```