# ListView getItemAtPosition(i) Method gives unreadable object

Tags: android, listview

I wanted to view the items selected in my listview with checkboxes. However, when I try to print out `lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()` it gives me a `` object. How can I convert this to a readable format?

```
  public void blockCheckedItems(View view) {  
    // int cntChoice = lv.getCount();
     checked = new ArrayList<String>();
     unchecked = new ArrayList<String>();

    int itempositions=adapter.getCount();

    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int countChoice = lv.getChildCount();

    Log.d("" + countChoice, "CountChoice===============================");
    Log.d("" + sparseBooleanArray,"sparseBooleanArray -------------------------");



     for(int i = 0; i < countChoice; i++)
     {

          if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
          {
              checked.add(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());

          }
          else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
          {
              unchecked.add(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
          }

      }
     for(int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++){
         Log.d("checked list&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&", "" + checked.get(i));
     }
     for(int i = 0; i < unchecked.size(); i++){
         Log.d("in unchecked list&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&", "" + unchecked.get(i));
     }


 }
```

Comment: get items from list of items not from view .

Comment: it is a simpleCursorAdapter. My list view is from android.R.id.list, although I specified @android:id/list in the layout view. Not sure why not able to get the item itself instead of unreadable data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
      {
          checked.add(Boolean.toString(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)));

      }
      else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
      {
          unchecked.add(Boolean.toString(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)));
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However when I tried it, eclipse gives me a syntax error : Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type boolean. Also since sparseBooleanArray contains only booleans, will not be able to get the item. Not sure how to see the item for all true booleans. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it is early morning here. I have updated my example using Boolean.toString(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) instead, might work better

Comment: No problem. Although the above method prints correctly, still gives me the boolean value instead of the item checked in the listview. Boolean only tells me whether it is checked or not, but not sure how to know which item was checked. Thanks again!

Comment: I understand better now. You have the i - position. 

.add(Boolean.toString(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) + " " + i);

will add the i position to the arraylist at least. Does this help?

Comment: just a small clarification, instead of printing the index of the item selected in the listview, i wanted to print the item itself. Not sure how to go about that. The listview contains checkboxes and is part o android.R.id.list class.

Comment: So you want to print the titles of the checkboxes? For instance "Are you are barbie girl?" YES/NO, then print "Are you are barbie girl?"

Comment: Yes. Now for instance my listview has contact names, like Emily Andrews, Susan John. I wanted to know which contact name was selected by the user.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996938/why-is-listview-getcheckeditempositions-not-returning-correct-values

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try the methods that are listed there!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above questions by changing the following code and using Cursor and keeping everyother part of the above code the same.

```
     for(int i = 0; i < countChoice; i++)
     {

          if(sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(i) == true) 
          {
              Cursor  cursor = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(i);
              String name = cursor.getString(1);
              checked.add(name);

          }
          else  if(sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(i) == false) 
          {
              Cursor  cursor = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(i);
              String name = cursor.getString(1);
              unchecked.add(name);
          }

      }
```