# Android Resources Not found exception in check item list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to make a listview with items populated from parse.com database. Each listitem has a checkbox and then on clicking a button, I would like a list of selected names. I have referred the following link :
http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html

The code I am using is this :

```
mNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //follow selected contacts here
                ArrayList<Users1> followedUsers = new ArrayList<Users1>();
                final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = mUserList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();
                Toast.makeText(ManualInviteActivity.this, checkedItemsCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; ++i) {
                   // Item position in adapter
                   int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
                   // Add team if item is checked == TRUE!
                   if(checkedItems.valueAt(i))
                      followedUsers.add(mUserAdapter.getItem(position));
                }
                for(Users1 u : followedUsers)
                {
                    Log.d("SELECTED TEAMS: ", u.getName());
                    //Toast.makeText(ManualInviteActivity.this, u.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

But the app crashes, giving me a resource not found exception(#0x0) on the line with the toast. If I move the toast elsewhere, it does not appear at all. 
How do i fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should replace with this

`Toast.makeText(ManualInviteActivity.this, String.valueOf(checkedItemsCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: This works. Though the toast displays 0 inspite of having list items selected. How do i fix this ?

Comment: You should use `Log.i(TAG, "Checked items: " + checkedItems.size());` to see the value of `checkedItems`. If it return 0 too, you should read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996938/why-is-listview-getcheckeditempositions-not-returning-correct-values)

Comment: I did that. Still 0. The actual problem I am facing is the last line of the code(the one in comment). I am trying to get the name of the users who are selected, but I do not get anything on button click. The other toast is just for debugging. How do I get the list of names ?

Comment: Have you set the mUserList choice mode to multiple?

Comment: Yes I have done that.